# IndexError: list index out of range on a Knapsack problem

Tags: python-3.x, list, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, index-error

The Question asks me to give an input weight, the number of items I can keep and the weight array. It asks me to calculate the maximum amount of weight I can carry (0-1 Knapsack: Dynamic Programming)

`W`: Input Weight
`n`: Number of items
`wt`: weight array

I get an Index Error for line 10 when I'm executing this code. It seems to be a very silly mistake at my end and I'm unable to figure it out after hours of running test cases.
The solution I googled up and found seems to be taking the value t[j][i] for every place where I write t[i][j]

```js
# Uses python3
import sys

def optimal_weight(W, wt, n):
     t = [[0 for x in range(n+1)] for y in range(W+1)]

     for i in range(1,n+1):
        for j in range(1,W+1):
             if wt[i-1]<=j :
                t[i][j]= max ( wt[i-1] + t[i-1][j-wt[i-1]] , t[i-1][j])
             else :
                t[i][j]= t[i-1][j]

     return t[n][W]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
    W = arr[0]
    n = arr[1]
    wt= list(map(int, input().split()))
    print(optimal_weight(W, wt,n))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = [[0 for x in range(n+1)] for y in range(W+1)]
```

Your outer list dimension here is `0..W`, and the inner is `0..n`; i.e. your valid index range is `t[0..W][0..n]`. So you would need `[j][i]` instead of `[i][j]`, since your `i` is going to `n` and your `j` is going to `W`.

Alternatively, you can flip how you define the list:

```
t = [[0 for x in range(W+1)] for y in range(n+1)]
```